Next-auth throwing a CallbackRouteError when CredentialsSignin error expected on signin with invalid credentials. Using Credentials provider
I am following Next JS's tutorials. Currently I'm doing chapter 15, but when I sign in with invalid credentials the error thrown is CallbackRouteError when it should be a CredentialsSignin. When signing in with "user@nextmail.com" and "123456", I can get access with no errors.
The only difference between my code and the tutorials should be the database interfacing. I use import postgres from 'postgres'; instead of import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres'; since I can run a Postgres database locally. I highly doubt this is the cause of the issue since the relevant subroutine (getUser) is basically identical.
I suspect this may be a bug with the next-auth since it's still in beta. The version is 5.0.0-beta.19. I would highly appreciate any input though since the code higher in the stack trace is difficult to wrap my head around. I can see that signIn is basically redirecting the user depending on the credentials, but Auth and AuthInternal are where I get lost.
Here's the console output from the development server by running with pnpm run dev as well as some print statements I included. I tried /login with a user not in the database, "asdf@asdf.com" with the password "asdfasdf". After the error, you can see that I signed in with a user that is in the database, "user@nextmail.com" with password "123456" which redirects to /dashboard.
 GET /login 200 in 27ms
[auth][warn][debug-enabled] Read more: https://warnings.authjs.dev#debug-enabled
authorize: {"success":true,"data":{"email":"asdf@asdf.com","password":"asdfasdf"}}
getUser: user: []
authorize: undefined
authorize: user not defined
Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev/#credentialssignin
[auth][debug]: callback route error details {
  "method": "POST",
  "query": {},
  "body": {
    "email": "asdf@asdf.com",
    "password": "asdfasdf",
    "callbackUrl": "http://localhost:3000/login"
  }
}
[auth][error] CallbackRouteError: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#callbackrouteerror
[auth][cause]: Error
    at Module.callback (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@auth+core@0.32.0/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/callback/index.js:226:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async AuthInternal (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@auth+core@0.32.0/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/index.js:66:24)
    at async Auth (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@auth+core@0.32.0/node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:126:34)
    at async signIn (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@5.0.0-beta.19_next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@1_zoejzgzdkvaggaqc67ldutlyty/node_modules/next-auth/lib/actions.js:51:17)
    at async authenticate (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./app/lib/actions.ts:125:9)
    at async C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page-experimental.runtime.dev.js:39:1202
    at async r_ (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page-experimental.runtime.dev.js:38:8514)
    at async nt (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page-experimental.runtime.dev.js:40:1270)
    at async doRender (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1473:34)
    at async responseGenerator (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1666:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1673:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:2007:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:2045:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:916:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:273:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:812:17)
    at async C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:339:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:157:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:336:24)
    at async invokeRender (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:173:21)
    at async handleRequest (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:350:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:374:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (C:\Users\brand\Repos\Examples\nextjs-dashboard\node_modules\.pnpm\next@15.0.0-canary.56_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704_react@19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-2024_ma5zmqaxqio5fndyl5qy52jyg4\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:141:13)
[auth][details]: {
  "provider": "credentials"
}
 POST /login 200 in 165ms
authorize: {"success":true,"data":{"email":"user@nextmail.com","password":"123456"}}
getUser: user: [{"id":"410544b2-4001-4271-9855-fec4b6a6442a","name":"User","email":"user@nextmail.com","password":"$2b$10$mv0x0rp1qbXqtvCvck1cnO7Pwmofe3kM1Fiz7oYTPD7GhybUbeSFy"}]
authorize: {"id":"410544b2-4001-4271-9855-fec4b6a6442a","name":"User","email":"user@nextmail.com","password":"$2b$10$mv0x0rp1qbXqtvCvck1cnO7Pwmofe3kM1Fiz7oYTPD7GhybUbeSFy"}
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See https://react.dev/link/warning-keys for more information.
 GET /dashboard 200 in 169ms
 POST /login 303 in 280ms


Here are the relevant source files which I'm pretty sure are identical to the tutorials'.
auth.config.ts:
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth';
 
export const authConfig = {
  debug: true,
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
      const isOnDashboard = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard');
      if (isOnDashboard) {
        if (isLoggedIn) return true;
        return false; // Redirect unauthenticated users to login page
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', nextUrl));
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
  providers: [], // Add providers with an empty array for now
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

The relevant server action:
'use server';
...
import { signIn } from '@/auth';
import { AuthError } from 'next-auth';

...

export async function authenticate(
  prevState: string | undefined,
  formData: FormData,
) {
  try {
    await signIn('credentials', formData);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AuthError) {
      switch (error.type) {
        case 'CredentialsSignin':
          return 'Invalid credentials.';
        default:
          return 'Something went wrong.';
      }
    }
    throw error;
  }
}

The client code that calls the server action:
login-form.tsx
'use client';
import { lusitana } from '@/app/ui/fonts';
import {
  AtSymbolIcon,
  KeyIcon,
  ExclamationCircleIcon,
} from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import { ArrowRightIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid';
import { Button } from './button';
import { useActionState } from 'react';
import { authenticate } from '@/app/lib/actions';

export default function LoginForm() {
  const [errorMessage, formAction, isPending] = useActionState(authenticate, undefined);
  
  return (
    <form action={formAction} className="space-y-3">
      <div className="flex-1 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 px-6 pb-4 pt-8">
        <h1 className={`${lusitana.className} mb-3 text-2xl`}>
          Please log in to continue.
        </h1>
        <div className="w-full">
          <div>
            <label
              className="mb-3 mt-5 block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
              htmlFor="email"
            >
              Email
            </label>
            <div className="relative">
              <input
                className="peer block w-full rounded-md border border-gray-200 py-[9px] pl-10 text-sm outline-2 placeholder:text-gray-500"
                id="email"
                type="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Enter your email address"
                required
              />
              <AtSymbolIcon className="pointer-events-none absolute left-3 top-1/2 h-[18px] w-[18px] -translate-y-1/2 text-gray-500 peer-focus:text-gray-900" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="mt-4">
            <label
              className="mb-3 mt-5 block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
              htmlFor="password"
            >
              Password
            </label>
            <div className="relative">
              <input
                className="peer block w-full rounded-md border border-gray-200 py-[9px] pl-10 text-sm outline-2 placeholder:text-gray-500"
                id="password"
                type="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Enter password"
                required
                minLength={6}
              />
              <KeyIcon className="pointer-events-none absolute left-3 top-1/2 h-[18px] w-[18px] -translate-y-1/2 text-gray-500 peer-focus:text-gray-900" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Button className="mt-4 w-full" aria-disabled={isPending}>
          Log in <ArrowRightIcon className="ml-auto h-5 w-5 text-gray-50" />
        </Button>
        <div className="flex h-8 items-end space-x-1">
          {errorMessage && (
            <>
              <ExclamationCircleIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-red-500" />
              <p className="text-sm text-red-500">{errorMessage}</p>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}


middleware.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';
 
export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth;
 
export const config = {
  // https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'],
};

auth.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { z } from 'zod';
import sql from '@/app/lib/db';
import type { User } from '@/app/lib/definitions';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

async function getUser(email: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
  try {
    const user = await sql`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=${email}`;
    console.log(`getUser: user: ${JSON.stringify(user)}`)
    return user[0];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch user:', error);
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch user.');
  }
}

export const { auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  ...authConfig,
  debug: true,
  providers: [Credentials({
    async authorize(credentials){
        const parsedCredentials = z
            .object({email: z.string().email(), password: z.string().min(6)})
            .safeParse(credentials);
            
        console.log(`authorize: ${JSON.stringify(parsedCredentials)}`);
            
        if (parsedCredentials.success){
            const { email, password } = parsedCredentials.data;
            const user = await getUser(email);
            console.log(`authorize: ${JSON.stringify(user)}`)
            if (!user){ console.log(`authorize: user not defined`); return null; }
            const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
            if (passwordsMatch){ return user; }
        }
        return null;
    }})
  ]
});

And, in case these may be useful, here are the versions:
$ pnpm list
Legend: production dependency, optional only, dev only

...

dependencies:
@heroicons/react 2.1.5
@tailwindcss/forms 0.5.7
@vercel/postgres 0.8.0
autoprefixer 10.4.19
bcrypt 5.1.1
clsx 2.1.1
next 15.0.0-canary.56
next-auth 5.0.0-beta.19
postcss 8.4.38
postgres 3.4.4
react 19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704
react-dom 19.0.0-rc-f38c22b244-20240704
tailwindcss 3.4.4
typescript 5.5.2
use-debounce 10.0.1
zod 3.23.8

devDependencies:
@types/bcrypt 5.0.2
@types/node 20.14.8
@types/react 18.3.3
@types/react-dom 18.3.0
eslint 9.7.0
eslint-config-next 14.2.5


$ node --version
v20.13.1



Sorry, I found the same issue and answer afterward. Looks like it is an issue with next-auth which can be fixed by switching the versions from 5.0.0-beta.19 to 5.0.0-beta.4

See here, this can solve the error of authjs signin redirect failure in server form action.
export const signInWithGithubAction = validatedAction(
    signInWithGithubSchema,
        async (data, formData) => {
        const { redirect: redirectParma } = data
        const res = await signIn('github', {
            redirect: !!redirectParma,
            redirectTo: redirectParma ? redirectParma : undefined,
        })
    redirect(res)
  },
)

Key Points: redirect(res) at the fuction last.
